# Regular Expression only if it finds matches n+ times

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex:

```
/^(\b[A-Z0-9]\w*\s*)+$/
```

That I am using to match post titles that have every word capitalized, and it works great, but I want it to only return true if it matches 3 times or more (or basically, if the title has more than 3 words) as I do not want it to catch basic titles or single words.

I can't seem to figure it out, when I try the following regex, nothing matches:

```
/(^(\b[A-Z0-9]\w*\s*)+$){3,}/
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Basically it needs 2 things:
1) Title must have at least 3 words.
2) Every word in the title must be capitalized (first letter uppercase).

Answer (score 1):

This one will match 3 consecutive capitalized words

`(?:[A-Z][a-z]+(?: |\?|,|:|!|-|$)+){3,}`

**Explanation**

`(?:...)` means it's a non matching group

`[A-Z][a-z]+` a capitalized word

`( |\?|,|:|!|-|$)+` followed by any of these characters, at least one time

`(...){3,}` Match those conditions at least 3 times

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XZcYeQ/7)

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to try and help! Your reply helped me just figured it out on my own. Your regex works, but it isn't exactly what I need. Because all words in a title need to be capitalized, not just 3 in a row.

I found that changing the + in my regex to {3,} works flawlessly!

'/^(\b[A-Z0-9]\w*\s*){3,}$/'

Comment: Glad you found it ^^